# Como filtrar un array con datos de otro array?

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

Necesito **filtrar un array** por un campo `categoria`. El campo `categoria` viene del resultado de otro array, **si tiene un solo valor me funciona, si tiene mas de un valor no.**

```
 const categoria= ["electricidad","gas"]

 const listTotal = [
     {category: "electricidad",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "gas",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "electricidad",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "luz",date:"01/01/01"} 
 ]
```

Este es un **ejemplo de los dos arrays**.

Mi código es este, (funciona si el array "categoria" es solo una, pero si es dos no)

```
listTotal.filter((v) => v.category.includes(categoria))
```

Comment: deberias agregar la salida esperada... como esperas tu resultados final?

Comment: const listCategory = listTotal.filter((v) => v.category.includes(categoriaUnica))
    console.log(listCategory)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes filtrar los elementos cuya `category` esté en el array `categoria`:

```js
const categoria= ["electricidad","gas"];
const categoria2 =["gas","luz"];

 const listTotal = [
     {category: "electricidad",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "gas",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "electricidad",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "luz",date:"01/01/01"} 
 ]

function filtra(array, filtro) {
 return array.filter(elem => filtro.includes(elem.category));
}

console.log("Filtrando electricidad y gas", filtra(listTotal, categoria));
console.log("Filtrando gas y luz", filtra(listTotal, categoria2));
```

Sencillo y es casi lo que has intentado, pero aquí estoy usando el método `includes` de la clase `Array`, no de `String`

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una opcion para tener un arreglo de objetos, donde las llaves son las categorias de tu primer arreglo y sus elementos estan filtrados.

```js
 const categoria= ["electricidad","gas","luz"]

 const listTotal = [
     {category: "electricidad",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "gas",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "electricidad",date:"01/01/01"},
     {category: "luz",date:"01/01/01"} 
 ]
 
 let ordenado = categoria.map((a, index)=>{
        return {
        [categoria[index]]:{
          elementos: listTotal.filter(x=>x.category == categoria[index])
        }
      }
 })
 

//Aca hay otra forma
let ordenado2 = categoria.map(a=>{
  return listTotal.filter(b=>b.category==a)
})
console.log(ordenado2)
```

Comment: Necesito en la misma estructura que listTotal

Comment: @AlbaHuertasDomínguez actualice la respuesta, revisa si te sirve

Comment: no.. porque me devuelve 3 objetos y lo necesito todo en el mismo

Answer (score 0):

Esto fue lo que hice yo, el forEach itera el array `categoria` luego adentro del forEach con el método `filter` busca los elementos que en `category` sean igual a **elementCatg** o sea la categoría iterada en ese momento.

> Edit: Ahora sí, itera todos los items del segundo array que en su `category` sean igual a elementCatg o sea la categoría iterada en el momento.
> Tenia el método `find` funcionaba bien pero solo buscaba el primero item que cumplía con la validaciones en cambio con `filter` busca todos los items que cumplen

**Resultado con el array `const categoria= ["electricidad","gas"]`**

```
const categoria= ["electricidad","gas"]
const listTotal = [
    {category: "electricidad",date:"01/01/01"},
    {category: "gas",date:"01/01/01"},
    {category: "electricidad",date:"02/01/01"},
    {category: "luz",date:"01/01/01"} 
]
categoria.forEach(elementCatg =>{
    let response  = listTotal.filter(elementList => elementList.category === elementCatg);
    console.log(response)
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado con el array `const categoria= ["luz"]`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ups funciona pero olvide algo, esta buscando el primer item que encuentre por eso no itera el otro objeto con la categoría `"electricidad"`

Comment: Ahora si funciona como debería ser cambie el método `find()` por el método `filter()`